# Change the styles of the visual composer in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

in the site on the Wordpress in a footer are loaded such styles

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='vc_pageable_owl-carousel-css-css'  href='site.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/owl-carousel2-dist/assets/owl.carousel.css?ver=4.4.2' type='text/css' media='' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='vc_pageable_owl-carousel-css-theme-css'  href='site.comу/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/owl-carousel2-dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css?ver=4.4.2' type='text/css' media='' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='animate-css-css'  href='site.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/animate-css/animate.css?ver=4.4.2' type='text/css' media='' />
```

I just can not find where they are loaded from. In the footer wp_footer (), in functions.php there is nothing like that. The validator swears at the missing element in media = '', where can this be fixed (on media = 'all)'?

Answer (score 0):

Those are loaded from the Visual Composer plugin. I wouldn't suggest editing the Visual Composer plugin to adjust the media param. Once you update the plugin the changes will be gone